# R&D in the European Union

Tags: european-union

Which country in the European Union has the lowest gross and per-capita research output (both academic and industry)?

Why is that?

Answer (score 3):

There's a nice, sortable table for R&D spending [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_research_and_development_spending). The EU country spending the least on a per capita basis is Romania (albeit with 2016 data). It's not exactly R&D output (how would you measure that?) but low spending correlates strongly with low output.

Wikipedia also gives [reasons for this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romania#Science_and_technology): corruption, low funding, and a considerable brain drain. [This](http://www.ad-astra.ro/journal/2/editorial_en.pdf) is the source cited. It is 20 years old at this point, but given funding remains low, it's probably still applicable to some extent.